# Are these molecular structures of cyclodecapentaene identical?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

> [image: Cyclodecapentaene]

I think that the above structures are identical compounds as **I** doesn't exist in the shown form but it would exist naturally in the **II** form, so these should be identical.

But these are mentioned to be geometrical isomers in a book that I was reading. Even if I assume that **I** existed in it's given form, then how can they be geometrical isomers? In **I**, there are two *trans* alkenes, three *cis* alkenes and in **II**, all five are *cis* alkenes.

So, are these compounds isomers or identical?

Comment: Both I and II (and there are more) are mere projections of a 3D molecular structure onto a 2D plane; shadows of the [Plato's Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_cave), or an impression of a [Flatland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)'s citizen of an object from our world. [Cyclodecapentaene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclodecapentaene) does possess geometrical isomerism, and I and II are indeed isomers, but to get an idea how it works you need to think in 3D and think stability in terms of angle strain.

Comment: Seriously and chemistry let apart, you can't compare existing X to non existing X' and claim there to be identical.

Comment: Well, you can tell that two groups are trans vs all-cis and that cis-trans is isomerism, so what's the point of the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make spring-and-ball models of both compounds, you can see that the two compounds are entirely different, and both are contorted.

[image]

The all-cis model on the left has all its hydrogens pointing outward, so the contortions of the carbon chain involve just carbon-carbon twisting to come close to 120 degree angles. The model of the cis-trans molecule on the right has two inward-pointing hydrogens (all the rest point out) which are sterically interacting so much that they introduce strain that is not evident from the carbon-only diagram in the original post. (If I put in all the hydrogens, the image is too cluttered.)

The fact that one is all cis and the other cis-trans certifies that the molecules are different, but the 2-D drawing can seem vague. The NMR spectra of these two compounds would be different. I can imagine the molecule on the left flipping all around (the model sure did!), but the molecule on the right seems pretty stuck.

Thinking in 3-D is easy after you've done it many times. But when you are starting out, it is helpful to make molecular models. And even if you've done it a million times, there are situations where your mental image is so fluid that you need to solidify it with a model, no matter how inadequate the model is. And then you mentally add onto the solid model.